# How to change paper size while printing a document in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am using C#'s PrintDocument class to create a pdf through a virtual postscript printer and ghostscript. I would like to be able to change the size of the page in the PrintPage event, i.e. while the page is being printed. I know it is possible to change page size before the document is printed, and also in the QueryPageSettings event.

This is my sample code to demonstrate the problem:

```
PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Printer Name";

// V This can change the page size V
doc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", 1000, 200);

doc.QueryPageSettings += (sender, args) =>
  {
  // V This can also change the page size V
  args.PageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", 1000, 200);
  };

doc.PrintPage += (sender, args) =>
  {
  // V This can not change the page size V
  doc.PrinterSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", 1000, 200);

  // V This changes the paper size for future pages V
  args.PageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", 1000, 200);


  args.Graphics.DrawString("Text", new Font("Courier New", 13.0f), Brushes.Black, 0f, 50);
  };

doc.Print();
```

Comment: how many pages are you generally printing.. I would think that you would need some sort of `foreach or for loop` when iterating through the page(s) if more than one..

Comment: I am generally printing between 1 and 100 pages. The multiple pages are handled by setting the HasMorePages flag on the event args passed into the PrintPage event function.

Comment: Why change paper size during printing ?